# Extra zero's being added when writing to file in C#

Tags: c#, regex, datetime, writetofile, tryparse

I have a csv file with certain records in it. Within these records are dates in various formats. I want to transform all of the formats into MM/dd/yyyy, where there is a 0 in front of any single digit month or day. The problem is that when it writes to the file it's adding a bunch of extra 0's and I cannot figure out why.  An example of my data is:

```
Title,Labels,Type,Current State,Created at,Accepted at,Deadline,Requested By,Description,Owned By,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment,Comment
pad,pad,epic,,9/26/2012 0:00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
655656 add security role xxxx,user updates,chore,accepted,7/20/2012 0:00,7/23/2012 0:00,,xxxx,"Call Number: 655656 
Client Name: xxxxx
Department: 
Address: xxxx
Phone: (xxx)xxx-xxxx
Open Date/Time: 6/25/2012 2:50:52 PM
Opened by: MAGIC 

Problem Description: Effective Date: 07/09/2012 12:00 a       
Area: CASE COMPASS.
Action: ADD ACCESS
Report/other Role: NONE
App Role: FIELD()

xxxx 7/18/2012 9:17 AM: created user id and assigned roles in enterprise security 

Notes:  

Problem Resolution: 7/19/12 - xxxx: Access granted, AD account added to the HL_Viewer security group.

CDS\xxxx -- S-1-5-21-508124448-3695470602-466989033-155771 

Magic URL:  http://magicweb02/magictsd 
",Jane Doe, Please verify (Jane Doe - 07/23/2012 0:00),verified (Jamie Doe -07/23/2012 00:00),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
655977 add security role xxxx,user updates,chore,accepted,7/19/2012 0:00,7/23/2012 0:00,,xxx,"Call Number: 655977
```

My code looks like this:

```
try
{
    string file = File.ReadAllText("C:\\\\Users\\hacknj\\Desktop\\mo_daily_activity_20160627_1412.csv"); 

    // Define bad date                
    Regex badDate = new Regex(@"(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})");

    // Find Matches
    MatchCollection matches = badDate.Matches(file);

    // Go through each match
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        // get the match text
        string matchText = match.Groups[0].ToString();                    

        // Define DateTime
        DateTime parsedDate;

        DateTime.TryParse(matchText.Trim(), out parsedDate);

        file = file.Replace(matchText, parsedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));                    
    }
    File.WriteAllText("C:\\\\Users\\hacknj\\Desktop\\TestFile.csv", file);
}
```

Here's a little of what the dates look like once it's been written to file:

```
pad,pad,epic,,000009/26/2012 0:00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
655656 add security role xxxx,user updates,chore,accepted,0000007/20/2012 0:00,00000007/23/2012 0:00,,xxxx,"Call Number: 655656
```

If I look at the data right before it gets replaced it looks fine. I do this via

```
MessageBox.Show("Match Text: " + matchText.Trim() + "\nParsed Date: " + parsedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing that is causing these extra 0's to be generated when writing to the file?

Comment: `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}` probably returns `9/26/2012` for `09/26/2012`. Iterating multiple times (and replacing) will cause extra `0`'s to be added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra zeros are a result of this line running in a loop:

```
file = file.Replace(matchText, parsedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

If the same date appears more than once in the file, every time your regex finds one the above line replaces *all* of them.  Therefore if the date required a leading zero, each time this line runs all the matching dates get a new leading zero.

Instead, you can use `Regex.Replace()` with a `MatchEvaluator` function to reformat the matched dates:

```
var newFile = Regex.Replace(file, @"(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})", m =>
{
    string matchText = m.Groups[0].ToString();
    DateTime parsedDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(matchText.Trim(), out parsedDate))
    {
        return parsedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
    else
    {
        return matchText;
    }
});

File.WriteAllText("C:\\\\Users\\hacknj\\Desktop\\TestFile.csv", newFile);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured that's where the problem was but didn't know that it was treating all of the same dates as one and therefore adding 0's every time to all of them. I'm going to have to go back and reread MatchCollections. Also, thanks for the MatchEvaluator. I'm going to have to look into this more so I can use it again later.

Answer (score 3):

Change

- `Regex badDate = new Regex(@"(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})");` to
- `Regex badDate = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}");` (remove the parentheses).

Change

- `string matchText = match.Groups[0].ToString();` to
- `string matchText = match.Groups[0].Captures.ToString();`

Also, if you want to capture the day, month, and year.  It will get the job done in a pinch.   No need to make replacements in a loop (strings are immutable anyway so this is a bad idea).  You don't have to worry about int.Parse throwing exceptions as you're covered by the function body will only execute when the content matches the patterns you defined (2 digits, 2 digits, 2 or 4 digits)

```
Regex badDate = new Regex(@"(?<Month>\d{1,2})\/(?<Day>\d{1,2})\/(?<Year>(20)?\d{2})");

File.WriteAllText(
    path, 
    badDate.Replace(
        file, 
        m => { 
            var year  = int.Parse(m.Groups["Year"].Value);
            var month = int.Parse(m.Groups["Month"].Value);
            var day   = int.Parse(m.Groups["Day"].Value);
            if (year < 2000) year += 2000;
            var datetime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            return datetime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
    )
);
```

The `(?<NamedGroup>RegexPattern)` syntax makes things a little easier to debug & the consuming code a little easier to read.  It's still regexes, but it's better than nothing.  I changed your year pattern to optionally accept a 20 followed by exactly 2 digits.  This should cover 2 or 4 digit years between 2000 and 2099.  Adjust as needed.  My apologies to your ancestors for the looming y2100 bug.